# How to watch a specific Java object by reference in IntelliJ IDEA's debugger?

Tags: intellij-idea

When debugging in IDEA, I would like to add a **New Watch** for a specific object (by reference); in the ideal case, by clicking some already shown variable. With other words: I want to watch an object even I don't have a variable/field in the currently debugged code pointing to it.

Use case: I'm debugging a complex data structure for which elements of this structure are processed one after another, e.g. *X*, *Y*, *Z*. When processing an element (e.g. *Z*), it may affect an already processed element (e.g. *X*). Now when debugging reaches processing of *X*, I would like to add a watch for *X*, then continue to debug processing of *Y* and *Z* where I would like to see how *X* changes.

Comment: Do you think conditional breakpoints relate to your question? You can stop after Z was processed, add a new watch manually and continue.

Comment: No, it's not about conditional break points. I want to watch an object even I don't have a variable/field in the currently debugged code pointing to it. I have updated the description.

Comment: Right clicking on the variable in the debugger tool window and selecting "add to watches" doesn't work for you?

Comment: No, because it will add the variable by name, like `data`. But `data` is only defined in a certain context and it may change its value.